# Mysql Multiplication Operation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to execute Multiplication Operation in a Mysql Query?

If my query is like this :

```
"SELECT registration.hosteladmissionno,
   registration.student_name,
   registration.semester,
   student_month.hosteladmissionno,
   student_month.student_name,
   student_month.semester,
   messexp.billmonth,messexp.billyear ,messexp.perdayrate,student_month.days_mess
   FROM registration,
    student_month ,messexp,blockexp
   WHERE  student_month.hosteladmissionno = registration.hosteladmissionno
    ";
```

How to execute multiplication operation within this query? say.. multiplication operation btw days_mess and

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multiplication operator is `*` :

```
mysql> select 100 * 2;
+---------+
| 100 * 2 |
+---------+
|     200 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In your case, if you want to multiply the values of two columns, you can use those columns, with the `*` operator between them :

```
select column1 * column2 as result
from your_table
where ...
```

Comment: (student_month.days_mess*perdayrate) AS result.. What should i give in Result part?

Comment: `result` is the alias I used, to give a name to the *(not-really-existant)* column -- to be able to access it from PHP, using that `result` name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select (days_mess * anotherFiled) as anyName
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there something that was too confusing in the docs:
[MySQL Reference: Arithmetic Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html)?

```
SELECT registration.hosteladmissionno,
    ## ...
    messexp.billmonth,messexp.billyear ,messexp.perdayrate,student_month.days_mess
    ## additionally generated column:
    messexp.perdayrate * student_month.day_mess AS account_payable
    ## ... end additionally generated column
```

FROM registration, student_month ,messexp,blockexp
   WHERE  student_month.hosteladmissionno = registration.hosteladmissionno

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (student_month.days_mess *  anotehr_field ), registration.hosteladmissionno,
   registration.student_name,
   registration.semester,
   student_month.hosteladmissionno,
   student_month.student_name,
   student_month.semester,
   messexp.billmonth,messexp.billyear ,messexp.perdayrate,student_month.days_mess
   FROM registration,
    student_month ,messexp,blockexp
   WHERE  student_month.hosteladmissionno = registration.hosteladmissionno
    ;
```