# MySQL convert minutes to seconds

Tags: mysql

I have stored minutes in normal number like 10 (10 minutes) not in any time format.Now i like to *convert minutes to seconds*. Is there any functions available in mysql

EX

> Result(seconds) = min * 60
>
> 600(seconds)    = 10 (min) * 60

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to update all the records in your table?

Comment: @ibu :No i like to convert it while i select particular row. I don't wanna update any thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Multiplication Operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374001/mysql-multiplication-operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already answered your own question: [use multiplication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_times).

```
SELECT foo.min*60 AS sec FROM foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do something like this:

```
SELECT (minutes * 60) as 'seconds' FROM table;
```